# KDE skin in Unity after installing KDE

Tags: unity, themes, kde

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I just installed KDE, so I could have both desktop environments and switch between on the login screen. However, when I logged back in with Unity, some programs now show up with the KDE skin. Is there any way to have both desktops separate, without any graphical overlap?

I must say, the only programs that keep the GNOME/Unity skin seem to be those developed by Canonical, while others (including programs **offered** by Canonical, such as Firefox) do change it.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/225600/44179