# Kde not removed?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, kde, removing

I have been used ubuntu 12.04 whit KDE, before I upgraded to 12.10 i removed KDE. Now some programs, icons and buttons still have the KDE skin while i'm using UNITY?

How can i fix this?

PS: i know that there are some other questions like this [KDE skin in Unity after installing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206920/kde-skin-in-unity-after-installing-kde) but it dont seems like he have **removed** KDE.

Comment: how did you install KDE (i.e. sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop)?

Comment: @psny in the software center kubuntu-full and kubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstanded your question

I think those apps are qt apps , If you want GTK look for these apps

1. Install qt4 setting from software centere
2. Launch it and select GTK appearance for apps

If it did'nt worked install kde system settings, and select interface as GTK+